# FFmpeg decode H264 video too slowly

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding

I am currently working on a project on iPhone using FFMpeg. I can decode all the formats I need but when I want to play a h264 video, ffmpeg decodes frames too slowly.

I tried to see where the problem is. I think that the options from the compilation of the library are good, decoding and displaying the frames are made ​​on different threads. In the end, it seems that it is the function `avcodec_decode_video2` that takes too long (3 to 4 seconds to decode 30 frames).

Comment: Sorry, but video editing is a slow operation. Even worse, you can't resurrect the dead. And you have to pay tax.

Answer (score 0):

25 - 30 frames per second is to slow for you

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

We've been having good luck with ffmpeg on all kinds of videos for 
serval years now.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried to run .mkv or .mov files on the various projects but I still can not read them at real speed. Maybe I didn't do good handling.

Comment: I was testing my code on an iphone 4 and I just test it on an iPhone 4S with a h264 video. So the problem would come that the processor is not powerful enough. There is no way to make it work on iphone less recent than the 4S?